# cannot read property '0' of parameter used in google app script function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Google App Script/JavaScript beginner here. I was looking for a way to copy a **column** from google sheet 1, transpose it, and copy it as a **row** in sheet 2 in the same spreadsheet. I found this 1-line script [here](https://gist.github.com/femto113/1784503), copied here for reference:

```
function transpose(a)
{
  return a[0].map(function (_, c) { return a.map(function (r) { return r[c]; }); });

}
```

I first implemented the transpose function on it's own successfully as follows, by first selecting a column of data in a sheet, go to script editor, and running this script:

```
 function transpose(a)
{
  var a = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getValues();
  var b = a[0].map(function (_, c) { return a.map(function (r) { return r[c]; }); });

  Logger.log('source data:', a);
  Logger.log('transposed data:',b);
}
```

Which outputs the following through the log:

- [20-02-29 14:50:38:585 EST] source data: [[1.0], [2.0], [3.0], [4.0]]
- [20-02-29 14:50:38:587 EST] transposed data: [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]]

showing that this works.

I'll be using transposing quite a few times in my final application, and even though I have something "hard-coded" that works, I wanted to create a stand-alone transpose function that I can call-out anywhere, and this is where I'm having trouble.

To try this idea I did the following:

```
var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getValues();

function transpose(a)
{
  return a[0].map(function (_, c) { return a.map(function (r) { return r[c]; }); });
}

var b = transpose(data);

Logger.log('source data:', data);
Logger.log('transposed data:', b);
```

but I get an error: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined (line 5, file "transpose")"

I don't understand why within the transpose function script, it's not understanding parameter "a" as a placeholder for whatever replaces it as the input later on, like in a any other custom parametrized function. It is obviously undefined the same way as "x" would be in a function 2*x.

What is going on? Maybe I'm touching on some nuanced syntax differences between pure javascript and google app script that I'm missing out?

In any case I would be expecting an error if the input to the function is the wrong type therefore "not being able to read the property", but in this case the input is the exact same thing as what worked in my first attempt, but the script errors-out before even getting to this point anyways.

Thanks,
Nestor

Comment: `data` is `undefined`. Probably, active Range is null

Comment: Hi @TheMaster that's the thing, it's not null, it does have data. This is the log it's producing, showing the active range has data and that the code is actually working but for some reason getting stuck with the error:   Feb 29, 2020, 4:01:08 PM Info source data: [[1.0], [2.0], [3.0], [4.0]]
Feb 29, 2020, 4:01:08 PM Info transposed data: [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]]
Feb 29, 2020, 4:01:08 PM Error TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at transpose(transpose:5:11)

Comment: *Info source data: [[1.0], [2.0], [3.0], [4.0]] Feb 29, 2020, 4:01:08 PM Info transposed data: [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]] Feb 29, 2020, 4:01:08 PM Error TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at transpose(transpose:5:11)* if it produces both logs correctly , when does it throw a type error?

Comment: If the error is after the second log, then the error  is down below and not in the transpose function. Are you calling transpose again with undefined or other variables? See [mcve]. Step1 is Start from scratch: i.e., a new clean project File>New.

Comment: @TheMaster I opened a new google sheet with new proyect and new sheet and it's still giving the error. In this new instance I'm only calling this function once

Comment: Could you [edit] to show the new script fully(top to bottom) and the logs?

Comment: Can you share a sheet with data and the script to reproduce the case?

Answer (score -1):

Is `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getValues();`  an asynchronous function?

You may need to use Javascript's `async/await` or `Promises` features.

What does `Logger.log('source data:', data);` produce?

Comment: Hi Nick, I don't think its an asynchronous function. 

Also all the logger functions produce this (I added a "2" in the string to make sure it wasn't showing me a log of a previous run):

Feb 29, 2020, 3:55:42 PM Info 2source data: [[1.0], [2.0], [3.0], [4.0]]
Feb 29, 2020, 3:55:42 PM Info 2transposed data: [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]]
Feb 29, 2020, 3:55:42 PM Error TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at transpose(transpose:5:11)

so I guess it's working but getting hung up on the error for some reason...

Comment: Could you please post the result of console.log(data)?  I'm not familiar with the Logger class.  Than you.

Comment: this is the result: Feb 29, 2020, 4:51:44 PM Info source data: [[1.0], [2.0], [3.0], [4.0]]
Feb 29, 2020, 4:51:44 PM Info transposed data: [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]]
Feb 29, 2020, 4:51:44 PM Error TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at transpose(Code:5:11)

Comment: .getValues() is not asynchronous.  This request for more information would have been better as a comment than as an answer to the question.